# Convert F# pattern-matching with condition to Scala

Tags: scala, f#, pattern-matching

How is it possible to convert a F# pattern-matching with when-condition to Scala?

I have the following code in F#:

```ml
match t0, t1 with
| "a", _ -> true
| b, "a" when not (b = "c") -> false
```

There is another post on this topic [Scala: Pattern matching when one of two items meets some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039715/scala-pattern-matching-when-one-of-two-items-meets-some-condition), but I can't get the baseline.

Comment: Sorry, this was my try with scala code. I edited it and inserted the F# code.

Comment: What, if (t0, t1) == ("c", "a")?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with F#, but looks like it should be almost 1:1 conversion. Here is Scala version:

```
(t0, t1) match {
    case ("a", _) => true
    case (b, "a") if b != "c" => false
}
```

Comment: For the pattern ("c", "a") this leads to an error. If b is always != c, the test is superflous, if not, a default case is necessary. Maybe this problem is already in the F#-code.