# Scala multiple type pattern matching

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I'm wondering how can I use multiple type pattern matching. I have:

```
abstract class MyAbstract

case class MyFirst extends MyAbstract
case class MySecond extends MyAbstract
case class MyThird extends MyAbstract // shouldn't be matched and shouldn't call doSomething()

val x: MyAbstract = MyFirst

x match { 
 case a: MyFirst => doSomething()
 case b: MySecond => doSomething()
 case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

So I'd like to write something like:

```
x match {
 case a @ (MyFirst | MySecond) => doSomething()
 case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

I saw similar construction in some tutorial, but it gives me error:

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : object MyFirst
[error]  required: MyAbstract
```

So is there a way to define few different types in on case clause? I think it would make code prettier. As if I will have 5 of them, I will write same code 5 times (calling doSomething()).

Comment: I think it's a XY-problem; you have a common superclass for all `doSomething` cases, why not match the `case a : MyAbstract` then...?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, that I have other classes, that extend MyAbstract class and shouldn't call doSomething.

Comment: Oh, OK, just wanted to clarify that :) You have a correct answer to your problem now though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match multiple cases classes in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837754/match-multiple-cases-classes-in-scala)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis for your case classes.
Case classes without parameter lists are deprecated.

Try this:

```
abstract class MyAbstract
case class MyFirst() extends MyAbstract
case class MySecond() extends MyAbstract

val x: MyAbstract = MyFirst()


x match {
   case aOrB @ (MyFirst() | MySecond()) => doSomething(aOrB)
   case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

If you have too many params for your case classes and don't like having to write long `Foo(_,_,..)` patterns, then maybe:

```
x match {
   case aOrB @ (_:MyFirst | _:MySecond) => doSomething(aOrB)
   case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

Or just:

```
x match {
   case _:MyFirst | _:MySecond => doSomething(x) // just use x instead of aOrB
   case _ => doSomethingElse(x)
}
```

But perhaps you just wanted singleton case objects?

```
abstract class MyAbstract
case object MyFirst extends MyAbstract
case object MySecond extends MyAbstract

val x: MyAbstract = MyFirst

x match {
   case aOrB @ (MyFirst | MySecond) => doSomething()
   case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: And there is no way to avoid parenthesis? As I have a few parameters and it becomes ugly:
case a @ (MyFirst(_, _, _, _, _) | MySecond(_, _, _, _, _)) => doSomething()

Comment: Did you miss `obj @ (_: MyFirst | _: MySecond)`?

Comment: I need `obj` in cases, where I'm using it in `doSomething` call. In my case, the call of `doSomething` wasn't using `obj`, so I don't need it. But anyway, thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Indeed I have. Let me edit my post to add it.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here - `scala> def foo(a: Any) = a match {
     |   case x @ (Int) => x
     | }
foo: (a: Any)Int.type

scala> val a = 100
a: Int = 100

scala> foo(a)
scala.MatchError: 100 (of class java.lang.Integer)
        at .foo(<console>:8)`?

Comment: It would be nice if the compile was smart enough to find the closest common type instead of defaulting to the input type.