# Pattern Match on Scala `class`

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I attempted to implement `unapply` for the class, `Foo`:

```
object Foo {        
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Int] = Some(x)  
} 

class Foo(x: Int)
```

However, it fails in the REPL when I attempt to use it:

```
scala> val f = new Foo(100)

scala> f match { case Foo(x) => x }
<console>:13: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Int
 required: Foo
              f match { case Foo(x) => x }
```

Why can't I use the `unapply` that I created for this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of `unapply` should be an instance of the type you want to match:

```
class Foo(val x: Int)

object {
    def unapply(f: Foo): Option[Int] = Some(f.x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `m-z`. Here's another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032429/409976) for readers of your solution.