# how to use pattern matching without case classes in scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, apply, case-class, syntactic-sugar

I heard that we can apply pattern matching in Scala without using case classes. Also, I do not mean just identifying the actual implementation class but also extracting various values from the object. Is it really possible? How can we achieve this?

I could not find an accepted answer that points to my solution in any of the question posted previously on similar topics. Hence, I decided to put up a new question.

Comment: it's a very generic question. But if a class implements the `.unapply` method, you should be able to access it's values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern matching over non-case class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031975/pattern-matching-over-non-case-class-in-scala)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case classes aren't magical, what they do under the hood is generate a lot of boilerplate code.
Between that, are the `apply` *(factory constructor)* and `unapply` *(extractor)* methods on the companion object of the class.
When you try to **pattern match** an object, what the compiler try to do is to call the **extractor method** of the companion object - thus, you only need to implement your own extractor object.

For example

```
class User(val id: Int, val name: String)

object User {
  def apply(id: Int, name: String): User = new User(id, name)

  def unapply(user: User): Option[(Int, String)] =
    Some(user.id, user.name)
}
```

Now you can create a match Users this way.

```
val user = User(3, "Luis")
def getId(user: User): Int = user match {
  case User(id, name) => id
}
getId(user) // 3
```

For reference see [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).

Answer (score 1):

Arnon and Luis solutions combined for demonstration purpose:

```
class A(val a: Int, val b: String, val c: Int)

// Handmade companion object for demonstration purpose only.
object A {
   def unapply(u: A): Option[(Int, String, Int)] =
    Some(u.a, u.b, u.c)
}

// No factory method found, so 'new' keyword is necessary.
val a = new A(1, "hello", 3)

/* With real case class the right side expression
    calls the unapply of the Object
   otherwise call must be explicitly.
*/
val Some((b, _, c)) = A.unapply(a)
// b: Int = 1
// c: Int = 3

def getId(user: A): Int = user match {
  case A(_, _, id) => id
}

getId(a) // 3
```