# How to handle different cases of Failure from Try

Tags: scala

I want to handle different cases of Failure (returned as Try).

**example code**

```
main(args(0)) match {
  case Success(result) => result.foreach(println)
  case Failure(ex) => ex match {
    case FileNotFoundException =>
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage)
    case StatsException =>
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage)
    case _ => {
      ex.printStackTrace()
    }
      System.exit(1)
  }
}
```

If its a `StatsException` or `FileNotFoundException` just print the message, for all other exceptions print a stack trace.

However ex is only ever a Throwable, and so `case StatsException` is a fruitless type test (a value of type Throwable cannot also be a StatsException.type according to IntelliJ)

Worse I get compile errors: `java.io.FileNotFoundException is not a value`

What's the best way to handle different cases of Failure in an idiomatic way?

Comment: I assume `StatsException` inherits from `Throwable` so `ex` can very well be an instance of `StatsException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify your own answer:

```
main(args(0)) map (_ foreach println) recover {
  case ex@(_: FileNotFoundException | _: StatsException) =>
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage)
    System.exit(1)
  case ex =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    System.exit(1)
}
```

In the first `case` clause we are matching two alternative. 
scala forbids declarations like `case ex: FileNotFoundException | ex: StatsException`, but we could assign whole match result via `@` symbol. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655817/scala-multiple-type-pattern-matching) for more details

Comment: Thanks - what does the @ in case ex@ mean?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
main(args(0)) match {
  case Success(result) => result.foreach(println)
  case Failure(ex: FileNotFoundException) =>
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage)
    System.exit(1)
  case Failure(ex: StatsException) =>
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage)
    System.exit(1)
  case Failure(ex) =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    System.exit(1)
}
```

Would be nice to have the System.exit(1) call shared by all Failure cases.

Comment: Well, you can write `case Failure(ex) => ex match { case ex: StatsException => ...; case ex: FileNotFoundException => ...; }; System.exit(1)`, almost like you tried initially.