# How to use cq in quasi quote to return the matched pattern

Tags: scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I am trying to write this `case authorDao: AuthorDao => authorDao` so that it returns the subclass of Dao itself.

When I use this quasi quote:

```
val daoType = TypeName(daoName)
val caseTerm = TermName(daoName.toLowerCase)

cases.append(cq"$caseTerm: $daoType=> $caseTerm")
```

It generates this

```
case (authordao @ ((_): AuthorDao)) => authordao
```

And if I do this

`cases.append(cq"${q"$caseTerm: $daoType"} => $caseTerm")`

It does this

```
case ((authordao): AuthorDao) => authordao
```

Both are produce compile errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found the answer here:

[Scala multiple type pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655817/scala-multiple-type-pattern-matching)

Basically

`case authordao: AuthorDao => authordao` is equivalent to this

**`case authordao @ AuthorDao(_) => authordao`**

So the final code is this

```
      val daoTerm = TermName(daoName)
      val caseType = TypeName(daoName.toLowerCase())
      val caseExpr = TermName(daoName.toLowerCase)

      cases.append(cq"$caseType @ $daoTerm(_) => $caseExpr")
```