# Bind extractor symbols multiple times in OR based pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible somehow to use an `OR` based pattern match that binds symbols to common elements, like:

```
import swing._
import event._

new Label {
  listenTo(mouse.clicks)
  listenTo(mouse.moves)

  reactions += {
    case MousePressed(_, point, mod, _, _) | MouseDragged(_, point, mod) =>
      println(s"mouse x = ${point.x}, y = ${point.y}, mod = $mod")
  }
}
```

Can I somehow make this work without writing to `case` statements with the same body (I know I can write an auxiliary function).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match multiple cases classes in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837754/match-multiple-cases-classes-in-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match multiple case classes, as it was indicated in a comment. However, you cannot use variables when you're doing so. So the `point` and `mod` variables cannot be used there.

However, if the `point` and `mod` fields are something that all mouse events should have you can create a common class for mouse objects and define your own unapply method in the common class' companion object:

```
abstract class MouseEvent {
  val point: Point
  val mod: Mod
}

object MouseEvent {
  def unapply(ev: MouseEvent): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((ev.point, ev.mod))
}

case class MousePressed(someField: Int, point: Point, mod: Mod, someField2: Int, someField3: Int) extends MouseEvent

case class MouseDragged(someOtherField: Int, point: Point, mod: Mod) extends MouseEvent

val ev: Any = MouseDragged(1, 2, 3)

ev match {
  case MouseEvent(point, mod) => {
    println(s"Values are $point and $mod")
  }
}
```