# multiple-origin extractions in the scala matcher

Tags: scala

I often find myself wanting to clump multiple matchers / extractors into the one line, but this doesn't seem to be allowed. e.g.:

```
text match {
  case regex1(a) | regex2(a) => a + "-"
}
```

(even though `a` is the same type for both matchers)

so I'm forced to refactor like this (which can get ugly when there are several of these, all handling different matches, mixed with inline responses)

```
text match {
  case regex1(a) => op(a)
  case regex2(a) => op(a)
}

def op(a: String) = a + "-"
```

is there a cleaner way? And will this be supported in Scala in the future?

Comment: Can we assume that the use of regex functions in your example is a pure coincidence and that you haven't confused regex matching with pattern matching?  I think you haven't, from your wording, but you could have chosen a clearer example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match multiple cases classes in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837754/match-multiple-cases-classes-in-scala)

Comment: @itsbruce this a perfectly legitimate use of the match clause! Regex has extractors that make it possible and is a solid example of the same extractor being used multiple times from different instances. This not a dupe of the question you reference (although it is somewhat related): here I am concerned primarily with obtaining the match parameters and is not at all specific to case classes.

Comment: although in the linked question, a commenter does express a desire for the very feature I would also like to have. (grep Mitch).

Comment: I'm not saying this is a misuse of case, just trying to get context for your intention.  Your question is more than somewhat related to the other question; it is a specific instance of that problem.  If there were a positive answer to the linked question, it would work for your too.

Comment: fine, I'll mark this as a dupe

Comment: The use of regex is relevant, because regex happen to have an or operator — so in *some* cases you can merge the regex directly (not if you have different regexps for the variable you're capturing).

Answer (score 3):

**No**, this is not possible in the general case. However, there are a few workaround that might be use to combine pattern matching cases:

- Match on a super class of the cases you are willing to group
- Use the `case a @ _ if boolexpr(a) or boolexpr(a) =>` construction
- Factorize the common code in a function, like you did in your example

And probably others. I don't think this is going to change any time soon as it would encourage writing cryptic mach/cases.