# Scala pattern match multiple types

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching

I have a code for extracting `Int` from `JValue` that should look exactly the same for multiple `JValue` subclasses, so I'm trying to avoid repeating myself. However, as it is (see below), scala thinks that `j` is a generic `JValue`, and that `j.values` returns a value of type `Values`, which, of course, does not have `isValidInt` and `toInt` methods.

```
jvalue \ name match {
  case j @ (JInt | JDecimal | JDouble) => {
    val num = j.values
    if (num.isValidInt) num.toInt.success else reportError(name + " is not a valid int")
  }
```

The question is what is the proper way to avoid repetition here? I'm not that crazy about converting a `JValue` into string, because this code works with json just parsed from a string into an AST. I started thinking about writing wrappers for the three types I need matched and implicit converters from these types into wrappers, and then making a superclass just for these wrappers for use as a pattern, but I am not sure how to pull it off.

And yes, I realize there are multiple similar questions here (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655817/scala-multiple-type-pattern-matching) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837754/match-multiple-cases-classes-in-scala)), but each of them only contains part of the solution at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an extractor to get the `Int` value out of arbitrary json values, then use the extractor in your mattern match.

```
object JsonInt {
  def unapply(json: JValue): Option[Int] = json match {
    case JInt(i) if i.isValidInt => Some(i.toInt)
    case JDecimal(d) if d.isValidInt => Some(d.toInt)
    case JDouble(d) if d.isValidInt => Some(d.toInt)
    case _ => None
  }
}

jvalue \ name match {
  case JsonInt(num) => num.success
  case _ => reportError(s"$name is not a valid int")
}
```

Comment: This seems like a clean solution at the first sight, but in reality it would look more like

`case JInt(i) => if (i.isValidInt) Some(i.toInt) else None //JInt's i is a BigInt`
and the same code for JDecimal and JDouble, which is precisely what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `isValidInt` checks, which can be less verbose than you stated. Another question: what Json library are you using? The `\` syntax looks familiar for `lift-json`, which has an `extractOpt[T]` method that you could use to directly extract an `Option[Int]` from any JValue.

Comment: Looked into `extract[T]` method. It can convert any numeric value to an `Int` (`extract[Int]`, that is), the only problem is it does not care about truncation, e.g. 2.1 gets converted to 2 without an error. If I have to write my own `Formats` that does care about truncation, it would involve the same level of verbosity as we have here.

Answer (score 1):

Scala has only limited support for structural typing. Seems like `JValue` is the lowest common ancestor of these three types. If you want, you may get around it by defining an implicit conversion from `JValue` to some wrapper class that will have `isValidInt` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't bother using structural typing, you can use `asInstanceOf` method to be able to use `toInt` and `isValidInt` method:

```
type IntExt = { 
  def toInt: Int 
  def isValidInt: Boolean 
}
jvalue \ name match { 
  case j @ (_: JInt | _: JDecimal | _: JDouble) =>        
    val num = j.values.asInstanceOf[IntExt] 
    if (num.isValidInt) num.toInt.success else reportError(name + " is not a valid int")
}
```